# tikzposter text justification in blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

I have started to use the `tikzposter` class and I wonder why the text inside blocks is flushed left by default instead of justified. How can I change the text alignment in blocks to be fully justified?

Comment: typically the columns in a poster (particularly in portrait mode) are fairly narrow - so a ragged right margin tends to look better than justified; try `align=justify` in the specs for your nodes

Comment: @prettygully Thanks, I tried `\block[align=justify]{Title}{Text}` and get `Error: `align' undefined in families `block'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

basically you don't like line 426 which says

```
        {\large\color{blockbodyfgcolor}#3}
```

If it said

```
        {\large\rightskip\z@skip\spaceskip\z@\xspaceskip\z@ 
                               \color{blockbodyfgcolor}#3\par}
```

then you would get justified text (and fix the `\par` issue of your other question.
It's a bit inconvenient to patch that you could just edit a local, renamed, copy and use that instead, or simpler just put

```
       \rightskip0pt
       \spaceskip0pt
       \xspaceskip0pt
```

at the start of your block entry, and

```
     \par
```

at the end. (The need for `\par` is a bug in the class file really, so you could report that)

If you do want to patch it, egreg suggests:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\block}
  {\large\color{blockbodyfgcolor}#3}
  {\large\rightskip\z@skip
   \spaceskip\z@\xspaceskip\z@
   \color{blockbodyfgcolor}#3\par}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

which would save editing a local copy of the class.

Comment: I was puzzled by this.  How is line 426 causing this to happen.  If I try to create my own MWE with something like `\begin{minipage}{5in} {\large\color{red}\mycontent} \end{minipage}` where `\mycontent` is just  filler text without any other LaTeX commands, I still get full justification.  So, what's happening here that I'm causing the lost of full justification?  Granted, my MWE was in an `article` class.  So, is this something at the level of the class?

Comment: @A.Ellett that line is wrong because it's missing `\par` the settings to 0pt that I suggested adding is _undoing_ a setting of `\raggedright` that has happened earlier, somewhere in the depths of tikz, I decided not to go there, as undoing it there is easier than finding out where raggedright is done and changing things not to do it

Comment: Thanks, editing the class file works perfectly, although patching the block command witch `xpatchcmd` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I don't know if it is related with this issue, but indenting paragraphs with `\indent` does not have any effect. I have made sure the `\parindent` length is defined in the preamble.

Comment: `\indent` is approximately never used in Latex: it just indents a paragraph by the amount it would be indented anyway (ie the value of `\parindent`)